# When adding CSS tumblr nav menu disappears

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a nav menu in tumblr. I disabled default mobile theme. But when I put in the CSS for Media Queries the menu disappears. How do I fix this?

I do like the responsiveness of the tumblr blog. I do wish I can keep the responsiveness, but also adding responsiveness to the menu. Is this achievable on tumblr?

I added this in the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/vr9xgox/K7fnmibsu/main-min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/q3xct0m/qVBnmxw9i/styles.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/q3xct0m/P9Unmxvt1/script.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Skin Care</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Skin Care</a>

         </li>

         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Make Up</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Masks</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yes I can provide fiddle. This is not showing up on fiddle either hmmm..    https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/

Comment: When you remove the media query in fiddle then menu also disappears and only seems to work when I do it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this piece of code:

```
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
```

Which is inside this enormous media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
```

Remove `display:none`. Hopefully that will fix the issue.

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/b1jczua7/1/

Comment: Wow that seemed to work! whats strange now is that the menu does no collapse. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need display none on the submenu's something like #cssmenu ul ul, display:none, but it depends on how the code is structured. You can keep updating the fiddle, but it might mean a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I'm going to start a new question.